# Android studio "Your app does not have the latest code changes.."

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to run app from Android studio, and it worked. But after stopping and starting few times this message appears.

Uninstalling and installing over again works, but as soon I restart the program the same message reappears.

"Your app does not have the latest code changes because it was restarted manually. Please run from IDE instead."

I am running everything from IDE. Nothing it done through the phone itself.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You saw this message because you killed and restarted your app manually after "Instant Run" applied changes to your app.

In Android Studio 2.0, a new feature was added called "Instant Run".

Instant Run is described in the [Android Studio Project Suite](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/instant-run):

> Introduced in Android Studio 2.0, Instant Run is a behavior for the Run  and Debug  commands that significantly reduces the time between updates to your app. Instant Run pushes changes to methods and existing app resources without building a new APK, so code changes are visible almost instantly.

A demo of Instant Run can be seen [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AefJXhCxrK8).

If you make a small change or changes, those changes will be implemented via Instant Run. However, since it *did not* build a new APK, killing that running instance of your app will discard those changes from the app installed on your device.

From [the Developer site:](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html)

> Note: If you need to restart your app after a crash, do not launch it from your target device. Restarting your app from your target device does not apply any of your code changes since the last cold swap or incremental build. To launch your app with all your recent changes, click Run (or Debug ) from Android Studio.

To have the changes permanently implemented to your app, kill it (actually make sure it gets killed, don't just hit the home button), and then build and run it again from Android Studio.

Comment: This is informative, i heard about android studio 2 instant run but didnt know it added changes without uploading new apk

Answer (score 18):

For me even killing the app and running from Android Studio still appeared the same sentence "Your app does not have the latest.."

What always works is **Run > Computer > Clean and Rerun 'app'**

Answer (score 2):

well if that message appears you don't need to uninstall the app

Just press the red button highlighted in the pic

[image]

it will stop your app and then if you run it again then it will run fine with latest code.

**NOTE:** you can press red stop button only if the app is running and your device is connected to the android studio, it will kill the app process and when you re-run it it will have the latest changes.

**if this doesn't solve your problem then you can go to Run>Clean & Re-Run.**

Hope it helps

Comment: this works so +1 it. but the comment by captJak has more info. so I accepted it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with Simulator (Nexus_5X_API-32_x32) + AS 2.1.1. I have to use Invalidate Cashes / Restart to rebuild and reinstall. In fact, that happens exactly after clicking that red square stop button above. Hopefully just a bug in AS.

Comment: Doesn't work on AS 2.1.1. The toast still appears, the only solution is hitting "Clean and Rerun".

Comment: This worked for me on Android Studio 2.1.2 (Stable Version) ! Awesome +1

Answer (score 2):

Use Rerun
When pushing code changes that affect certain initializers, such as changes to an app's onCreate() method, you need to restart your app for the changes to take effect. To perform an incremental build and restart the app, click Rerun .

If you need to deploy a clean build, select Run > Clean and Rerun 'app'  from the main menu, or hold down the Shift key while clicking Rerun . This action stops the running app, performs a full clean build, and deploys the new APK to your target device.

I tested the way of Shifting key while clicking Rerun, it works fine.

Link : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html